# Fortran woes. How can I make a more efficient simpler interface. Maybe use Bash script or VBA?

Tags: bash, user-interface, vba, excel, fortran

I work for a firm that is using a bunch of old Fortran code. I have pretty much become fluent in bash scripting so that I can run all these programs in a timely manner.

Currently I have to run ~ 13 different Fortran programs to get one result for 1 sector out of 11. So that is 143 programs for one complete result. I would like to be able to create 8 or 9 complete results using different inputs in the programs in a timely manner.

An Ideal situation would be a set up in say a GUI where on separate tabs you fill out input forms, then when all your forms are filled you can just click a button and you have your result. Go back and change a few variables in the forms and click, poof another result.

I'm at a crossroad because I already have a bash script that can almost do this. I can't however figure out a way to mix it with a "stand alone" GUI. I have no Fortran background but assume that I may have to learn to get this to work. I do however have a little VBA knowledge.

So what I am asking is what is the best way to go about this? Use VBA to write a shell script and execute? Have some kind of combine Fortran GUI interface that will pass a bunch of variables to the programs?

The programs are set up to take input from user and from files created by the previous programs. As of now here is how the shell script and program prompts are set up:

```
 #This file is a combination of NEWlen to bbdist as of now 4/5/2012
 #M. Conley

 ####################################################################################
 ##################### Please input all of your back break      #####################
 ##################### parameters in the block bellow!          #####################
 ####################################################################################
 project="Cobre Panama, Botija -2012"

 #Example of format
 #sec1="lwmin lwmax rwmin rwmax numberofcells"
 #----------------------------
 #| S |M |Max|Max| M| N |S
 #| e |i |Lft|Pln| a| u |e
 #| c |n |Wed|   | x| m |c
 #| t |  |   |   |  | b |t
 #| o |L |or |or | R| e |o
 #| r |e |   |   | i| r |r
 #|   |f |Min|Min| g|   |
 #|   |t |PS |Rgt| h| o |
 #| v |  |   |Wed| t| f |D
 #| a |W |   |   |  |   |D
 #| r |e |   |   | W| c |R
 #|   |d |   |   | e| e |
 #|   |  |   |   | d| ls|
 #---------------------------
 sec1="96 166 206 276 20 186"
 sec2="127 197 237 307 20 217"
 sec3="178 248 288 358 12 268"
 sec4="225 295 335 45 21 315"
 sec5="258 328 368 78 14 348"
 sec6="297 7 47 117 31 27"
 sec7="315 25 65 135 32 45"
 sec8="342 52 92 162 18 72"
 sec9="12 82 122 192 12 102"
 sec10="30 100 140 210 18 120"
 sec11="45 115 155 225 22 135"

 numofsec=2
 cmaxdip=90
 cmindip=0

 smaxdip=90
 smindip=20

 den=165.0

 l1r1prob=0.2000
 p1prob=0.2000
 jslf=001.00

 cellwidth=30
 ####################################################################################
 ##################### Start of Automation Loop. All Parameters #####################
 ##################### Have already been defined above!         #####################
 ##################### DO NOT WRITE BELOW THIS POINT!!!!!!!!    #####################
 ####################################################################################

 ########## Check for celdisx in directory #######
 if [ ! -e celdisx ]; then
 echo -e "\a""\x1b[31;01m""You are missing the CNI celdisx program from your directory!"
 echo -e "\a""\x1b[32;01m""Terminating Script - No results calculated."
 tput sgr0
     exit 0
 fi

 ########### Get Length and Spacing ###########
 echo "Please enter desired Mean Joint Lenght in meters, use 2 decimal places (#.##)"
 read jlen
 echo "Please enter desired Joint Spacing in meters, use 2 decimal places (#.##)"
 read jspace
 temp=$jlen
 jlen=$(echo "$temp" | awk '{ printf "%6s", $1}')
 temp=$jspace
 jspace=$(echo "$temp" | awk '{ printf "%5s", $1}')
 replace=$jlen$jspace
 #####

 ########### Get and Make new directory ##########
 echo "Please type the name of the new folder you wish to create to place this"
 echo "iteration of back break into."
 echo "No spaces please. Use _ or - in place of spaces."
 read dirname
 if [ -d $dirname ]; then
 rm -r $dirname
 fi
 mkdir $dirname
 cd $dirname
 for (( id = 1 ; id <= $numofsec ; id++ ))
 do
 if [ -d sec_$id ]; then
 rm -r sec_$id
 fi
 mkdir sec_$id
 done
 cd ..

 ########### Copy origional .dgl files into sec dir ####
 for (( id = 1 ; id <= $numofsec ; id ++ ))
 do
 cp s${id}.gld ${dirname}/sec_$id
 cp celdisx ${dirname}/sec_$id
 cp KNRST ${dirname}/sec_$id
 done

 ####################################################################################
 ##################### Start of Back break Programs. All Dir &  #####################
 ##################### Root .gld  have been placed.             #####################
 ####################################################################################
 cd $dirname


 for (( id = 1 ; id <= ${numofsec} ; id++ ))
 do

 #### Change into iteration and sector dir ###
 cd sec_$id

 #### change 1 to 01 bb prog very specific about 6 char strings wtf #####
 ida=${id}
 if [ ${#id} -eq 1 ]; then
 ida=0${id}
 fi


 ########## Check for celdisx in directory #######
 if [ ! -e celdisx ]; then
 echo -e "\a""\x1b[31;01m""You are missing the CNI celdisx program from your directory!"
 echo -e "\a""\x1b[32;01m""Terminating Script - No results calculated."
 tput sgr0
     exit 0
 fi

 #Creates Length File w/ user input Length & Spacing
 sed -r "2,$ s/^(.{73})(.{11})/\1$replace/" <s${id}.gld >s${ida}LeN


 ################### Runs Cell programs #######
 secid=sec${id}
 set ${!secid}

 celsrt<<xxxxx
 s${ida}LeN

 sec_${ida}.srt
 sec_${ida}.f
 Y

 TEST sec_${ida}
 3
 1
 ${2},${1},${cmaxdip},${cmindip}
 N

 2
 ${3},${2},${cmaxdip},${cmindip}
 N

 3
 ${4},${3},${cmaxdip},${cmindip}
 N

 sec_${ida}mv.met

 xxxxx
 met2acad <<xxxxx
 sec_${ida}mv.met
 e
 1

 xxxxx
 celdisx<<xxxxx
 sec_${ida}.srt
 sec_${ida}.dis
 m
 sec_${ida}.tbl
 ${5}




 xxxxx


 ############# run bbstdi ################
 rm -f s${ida}sdi

 bbstdi<<xxxxx
 1
 s${ida}sdi
 y
 ${id}sdi.rpt
 sec_${ida}.dis

 xxxxx



 ########### Run bbhst #######
 var=sec${id}
 set ${!var}

 bbhst<<xxxxx
 ${prjt} - ${area} - Sector ${ida}
 99
 99
 1
 s${ida}LeN
 ${3},${2}
 ${smaxdip},${smindip}
 s${ida}P1h
 Sec${ida}_hist.met
 xxxxx
 met2acad<<xxxxx
 Sec${ida}_hist.met
 e
 1

 xxxxx


 ######### Getting the DIST! ##########
 echo "Processing Sector ${ida}!!!"
 bbdist<<xxxxx
 s${ida}P1h
 s${ida}P1d

 xxxxx


 ########## Get set Numbers and run bbrsco ########

 lw1setn=$(sed -n "1p" s${ida}sdi | cut -c 11-14)
 ps1setn=$(sed -n "2p" s${ida}sdi | cut -c 11-14)
 rw1setn=$(sed -n "3p" s${ida}sdi | cut -c 11-14)

 #echo -e "$lw1setn\n$ps1setn\n$rw1setn"

 bbrsco<<xxxxx
 s${ida}rs ${ida}
 QUIT ,0.0
 GRD,${lw1setn} 100
 GRD,${ps1setn} 100
 GRD,${rw1setn} 100
 END
 xxxxx

 ############ Run bbpldc, create plan shear In ####
 var=sec${id}
 set ${!var}

 bbpldc<<xxxxx
 s${ida}rs
 ${ida},${6}
 s${ida}sdi,s${ida}P1d
 2,${den}
 1
 090.
 s${ida}P1c,$ps1setn
 STOP
 NO
 xxxxx

 ########### Calc Plane Shear bbplaf #######

 bbplaf<<xxxxx
 s${ida}P1c,s${ida}P1f,${ps1setn}
 R,090.,090.,001.
 R,009.,018.,009.
 T
 N
 xxxxx

 ######### Compute wedges ##################
 var=sec${id}
 set ${!var}

 bbwedc<<xxxxx
 s${ida}rs
 ${ida},${6}
 s${ida}sdi
 2,${den}
 1
 009.
 L1R1wc,${lw1setn},${rw1setn}
 ${2},${1},${smaxdip},${smindip}
 ${4},${3},${smaxdip},${smindip}
 STOP
 NO
 xxxxx

 for infile in L{1..1}R{1..1}wc
 do
 oufile=$(echo $infile | sed "s/c/f/g")

 bbwedf<<xxxxx
 ${infile},${oufile},4657,1500
 R,090.,090.,001.
 R,009.,018.,009.
 T
 M,M
 xxxxx

 done

 ######### combine Plane & Wedge Failures ####

 bf7com<<xxxxx
 YES
 ${ida}theo
 D,${ida}pred,${jslf}
 W,L1R1wf,${l1r1prob}
 P,s${ida}P1f,${p1prob}

 ${cellwidth}


 xxxxx

 ######## Plot the Curve ############
 var=sec${id}
 set ${!var}

 bfaplt<<xxxxx
 ${ida}theo
 1
 18
 DRY
 ${project} - Backbreak Results
 Sector ${ida} Wall Orientation DDR ${6}
 Joint Set Lenght Factor ${jslf}
 April 2012
 Trial Runs
 ${ida}bfa.met
 ${ida}theo
 9
 ${ida}pred
 18
 ${ida}pred
 9


 xxxxx
 met2acad <<xxxxx
 ${ida}bfa.met
 e
 1

 xxxxx

 ######## Make Table ####

 #### Change out of sector name

 cd ..

 #END LOOP
 done

 cd ..
```

ANY HELP OR POINTERS WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED!!!!!!!!

Comment: In these situations, my GUIs generally just create input files or commandline arguments based on the inputs and then run the programs via system calls ...  If you can piece together the inputs using bash, why not use whatever language you use to create the GUI?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: look at tcl scripting. Good luck.

Comment: [This](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/Gtkdialog) might work for you.

Comment: If you do this for your colleague/boss/customer who refuse to learn any scripting language, you follow suggestions from above three.  But if you are the one who has to run problem, i'd stick with bash.  why bother writing GUI?   If preparing input file using bash is tedious (i know fortran program may be picky in text file format, and bash sometime do not behave when parsing variable), lean a bit more powerful scripting tool like python, perl, ruby etc.  even if you decided to write GUI, you still have to get this preparing input part done.

Answer (score 3):

I understand your confusion, but it is very hard, if not impossible to
give any definite advice at this point with the data available.

First, your environment; you mention **bash scripting** (even gave an
example) which points me to a ***nix box**, but then you mention **VBA** which
one usually associates with **Windows systems**.
***Are you on a Windows box, and using bash from a environment such as
cygwin or?***

Second, the "nature" of your fortran programs - what do they do? How are
they **structured** and so on... ***Fortran can indeed be mixed with a GUI
interface - that is not even a fortran problem, but more of a problem of
choosing compatible versions of your fortran compiler and the other
environment (MATLAB via. mex files, Excel via .dll files, ...) and then
mixing them up. It is an area for itself.***
It can be done, and it is done, but I repeat, this is all talk in
general.

There are also some interfaces such as **DISLIN, GINO** or **Winteracter** (you can
google the names for more information), which enable creating "Fortran
GUIs". I haven't worked with either of the two, but have heard good
things about both.

***Your fortran programs, depending on how are they structured now, may
have to be modified a bit (re-organized). Will this present a problem
depends on how are they written/structured originally. You may have to
learn a bit about the language to do this part.***

***Separated like this, they're all problems which can be solved. It would
be wise if you would search through SO for questions dealing with
similar matters, and try to see which approach would fit you the most.
After that maybe refine the question, after you've choosen the path to
go.***

Give me a call in the comments, if any of this makes or doesn't make
sense.

Comment: dislin, called from Fortran, call also create simple GUIs.

Comment: @M.S.B. - Since I'm using it for plotting all the time, I can't believe I missed to mention it :/

Comment: All this advice is great! Thank you guys so much! It looks like now I'll need to do some more research and decide which way to go. I am working physically on a Windows box and then using telnet to connect to a server running Linux. I am basically doing it for my colleagues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bash, why not try zenity.  It can be used to pop up a form that can be filled in and the results will come straight back to bash, then you can use the rest of the bash script as it stands.

The other alternative is to use curses or if you are OK with Fortran, write your own with VT100 sequences.

If you're running on a windows environment, try writing it as a hypertext application (HTA).  This is basically a web page with a bit of javascript/vbscript (whichever you fancy).  Start here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(v=vs.85).aspx